# Symfony2 - Json - Clean up header response

Tags: php, json, symfony, http-headers

I use symfony2 and create a web service :

```
 $response = new JsonResponse();
 $response->setData(array(
        'dt' => time()
 ));
 return $response;
```

The response have this header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 23 Dec 2014 10:23:06 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.12
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Debug-Token: 27ccd9
X-Debug-Token-Link: /capteur/web/app_dev.php/_profiler/27ccd9
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
```

However the electronical device who call this webservice need a smaller header like this :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
{"dt":1418812347}
```

How could I accomplish this with symfony2 ?
Symfony always add a lot of things in the header ...

Thanks !

**EDIT**

In production mode some header are disabled.
Whith some .htaccess rules :

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header unset X-Powered-By
      Header unset Keep-Alive
      Header unset Content-Length
      Header unset Server
      Header unset ETag
      Header unset Cache-Control
      Header unset Last-Modified
      Header unset Date
      Header unset Accept-Ranges
      Header unset Connection
      Header unset Content-Type
</IfModule>
```

some header are still here :

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Wed, 31 Dec 2014 13:48:20 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

After a lot of try, I think it's the smallest header available under apache server.

Comment: It's possible to overwrite the headers set by JsonResponse, have a look at this http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#creating-a-json-response

Comment: Even better here http://api.symfony.com/2.2/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.html#method_create

Comment: `$response = new JsonResponse(array('dt' => time()),'200', $headers = array());
return $response;`
give me the same headers ...

Comment: Try to pass a non empty header, maybe when `$headers` is an empty array it put the default values

Comment: Also you're seeing a lot of extra values because you are testing this in the dev environment. Run the same command in production and see what it returns.

Comment: Yes you're right. X-Debug-Token are for development only. Other value are provide by Apache... so the problem is dispatch between JsonResponse / Apache